# android + pthread + c++ = SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, android, pthreads

The following code compiles and runs on standard linux:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        void go_thread();
        void stop_thread();
    private:
        static void* worker( void* param );
        pthread_t m_pt;
};

Foo::Foo()
{
    m_pt = 0;
}

void Foo::go_thread()
{
    int success = pthread_create( &m_pt, NULL, worker, static_cast<void*>(this) );

    if( success == 0 )
    {
        cout << "thread started" << endl;
    }
}

void Foo::stop_thread()
{
    int success = pthread_join( m_pt, NULL );

    if( success == 0 )
    {
        cout << "thread stopped" << endl;
    }
}

void* Foo::worker( void* p )
{
    cout << "thread running" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.go_thread();
    f.stop_thread();
    return 0;
}
```

and produces the following output:

```
$ ./a.out
thread started
thread running
thread stopped
$
```

This code also builds with the Android NDK (r5b).  However, when I adb push the resulting executable to a device and run it, I get a SIGSEGV before main() even runs.  I've isolated the issue down to `pthread_create()` It seems the mere existence of this call in my code, never mind execution, causes my prog to seg fault.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your error checking is wrong.  pthread_create & join will return 0 on success, otherwise an integer signifying the error.  You might be failing for a reason and not know about it.

Comment: yep, good eye.  I've corrected the post but the core issue still remains.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be combining iostream with pthread.  I went through and replaced all couts with printf()s, removed the using clause, and removed the iostream header.  The code compiled and ran with no issue on the device.  I wonder if this is something Google should be made aware of?

The final (working) code looks like:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        void go_thread();
        void stop_thread();
    private:
        static void* worker( void* param );
        pthread_t m_pt;
};

Foo::Foo()
{
    m_pt = 0;
}

void Foo::go_thread()
{
    int success = pthread_create( &m_pt, NULL, worker, static_cast<void*>(this) );

    if( success == 0 )
    {
        printf( "thread started\n" );
    }
}

void Foo::stop_thread()
{
    int success = pthread_join( m_pt, NULL );

    if( success == 0 )
    {
        printf( "thread stopped\n" );
    }
}

void* Foo::worker( void* p )
{
    printf( "thread running\n" );
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.go_thread();
    f.stop_thread();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It may not be this but try making the function called by pthread create a normal c-function (i.e. declare it as extern "C") not a static member function:

This is because technically the calling convention for static members may be different from the C calling convention that is used by the C-library pthread (though a lot of the times they are the same (which is why it works on your linux box) in my opinion it is not worth the porting risk).

```
extern "C" void* start_the_thread(void*);

void* start_the_thread(void* data)
{
    Foo*  theObject = static_cast<Foo*>(data);
    // In Java if your Foo had been derived from Runable
    // This is s where theObject->run() would have been called.
    return Foo::worker(data);
}

int success = pthread_create( &m_pt, NULL, start_the_thread, static_cast<void*>(this)
```

Comment: `[basic.compound]` and `[expr.unary.op]` decree that pointers to static members are interchangeable with pointers to free functions.  That doesn't completely rule out incompatibility with the `extern "C"` calling convention, but you'll need some other implementation-specific fix to change the calling convention.

Comment: @Ben: C++ functions. Not C functions (aka extern "C"). Note pthread is a C library and thus uses the "C" calling convention on pointers it receives. Once inside the start_the_thread() function we can of course call the static member function normally.

Comment: @Martin: Correct, the language linkage is part of a function pointer type.  But it's application of the `extern "C"` linkage, not moving the function outside the class, that fixes the type.  And since it is a type mismatch, the compiler should have thrown an error -- function pointers are never implicitly converted.

Comment: @Ben: I was not aware that you could apply extern "C" linkage to a static member method. If you can that will solve the problem. But as I don't think you can (I could be wrong) the solution must be to move it outside the class. Its not the compilers fault (the types are identical (linkage is how they called not part of the type)), I have never seen the compiler throw this as an error yet I have seen this exact problem many times before. Its a 50/50 bet on capability between calling conventions. Note: like 80% of stats the 50/50 is made up (lets just call it a weighted coin toss).

Comment: @Martin: You can't apply `extern "C"` to a member function (static or otherwise).  But being a free function is not enough.  Anyway, if the function pointer formed from a C++ function was incompatible with `pthread_create`, the compiler is obligated to reject the program.  The standard doesn't permit implicit conversion of function pointers, and this diagnostic isn't optional.

Comment: @Martin: linkage IS part of the type, according to `[dcl.link]` and `[expr.call]`.

Comment: @Ben: it would be nice if they did refuse to compile, but I have never seen that to be the case.

Comment: @Ben: I though I had made it very clear it needed to be a C-function (aka `extern "c"`) in the description above (by my use of `extern "c"`). I have modified the description to make it even more explicit.

Comment: @Martin: Also, it's `extern "C"` with a capital `C`.  Handling of other strings, such as lowercase `c`, is implementation-specific.

Comment: Unfortunately the extern "C" trampoline didn't seem to work, but the theory makes perfect sense.  I did finally figure out the issue...

Comment: @awm129 - Please share what the problem was.

Comment: @Duck see the the answer I posted above.  Although this seems to work, its unclear on 'why' it works...  I posted a question to the ndk google group and no one seems to have any ideas.  I'm not sure what to make of it.